Netlisting errors in Pspice "ERROR(ORNET-1163): Unable to create netlist file."
I'm simulating a simple BiCMos Darlington Circuit from the "Analysis and Design of Analog Integrated Circuits" book in Pspice Orcad Software. I don't know why when I'm trying to run the simulation, I get the following errors related to netlisting. And also some pins of the circuit are marked green! Maybe that's also a cause of the error!?
I'm quite beginner and I'd be happy if someone can walk me through that and helps me to solve these errors.
Thanks in advance.

This is by the way my session log, that's useful too:
Checking Schematic: SCHEMATIC1
--------------------------------------------------
Checking Electrical Rules 

Checking For Single Node Nets

Checking For Unconnected Bus Nets

Checking Physical Rules 

Checking Pins and Pin Connections

--------------------------------------------------
Checking Schematic: SCHEMATIC1
--------------------------------------------------

INFO(ORCAP-2242): Checking Incorrect Pin Group Assignment

Report for Invalid References

Report for Duplicate References

--------------------------------------------------
Checking Entire Design: BICMOS-DARLINGT 
--------------------------------------------------
ERROR(ORCAP-2213): Checking Physical Rules
ERROR(ORCAP-36002): Property "PCB Footprint" missing from instance BT1: SCHEMATIC1, PAGE1 (1.20, 3.80). /BT1:  SCHEMATIC1, PAGE1  (1.20, 3.80) 
ERROR(ORCAP-36002): Property "PCB Footprint" missing from instance BT2: SCHEMATIC1, PAGE1 (6.00, 1.40). /BT2:  SCHEMATIC1, PAGE1  (6.00, 1.40) 
ERROR(ORCAP-36002): Property "PCB Footprint" missing from instance Q2: SCHEMATIC1, PAGE1 (4.60, 2.40). /Q2:  SCHEMATIC1, PAGE1  (4.60, 2.40) 

INFO(ORCAP-2211): Check High Speed Properties Syntax

INFO(ORCAP-2212): Check Power Ground Mismatch

Reporting Unused Refdes in multiple part packages
Part                           Quantity                        Reference
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO(ORCAP-2191): Creating PSpice Netlist
INFO(ORNET-1041): Writing PSpice Flat Netlist .\
Cannot remove file .\
ERROR(ORNET-1163): Unable to create netlist file.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO(ORCAP-2282): The following 1 points have been identified as net connectivity change points from the last operation
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(4.20, 2.90)
INFO(ORCAP-2191): Creating PSpice Netlist
INFO(ORNET-1041): Writing PSpice Flat Netlist .\
Cannot remove file .\
ERROR(ORNET-1163): Unable to create netlist file.



is it resolved? I also encountered the same problem

no actually I don't how to resolve it unfortunately.. I only named the footprint and changed the model and the parts. it resolved but got into the same problem afterwards

I solved it strangely. The same model would report an error yesterday; today I reopened the computer and ran the simulation and it worked. Maybe it would be useful to leave it alone for a while.

When you create a netlist,  it is traditinally used to create a PCB. For a PCB the Footprint (physical layout of component with pads, keepout, body and so on) for every component used is required.
So you need to define the footprint to be used for BT1, BT2 and Q2 and you should be good.

I only want to simulate the bias currents and voltages of the circuit. Actually I don't need the PCB configurations. But despite entering the PCB footprints for these three components I'm getting again an error. I think the same error!!
